# Codecademy Building an Address Book 5/6

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing the activity, referenced above, wherein the program needs to search for an entry by last name, find that entry, and then return the first and last name of all entries that match the last name.
The activity can be found [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/building-an-address-book/0/5).

My code displays the correct message after running (Bob Jones), but it comes with an error message that says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined"

I cannot figure out where the error message is coming from, nor how to resolve it. Any input would be welcome.

My code:

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list() {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}

/*Create a search function
then call it passing "Jones"*/
function search(lastName) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].lastName === lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);    
        }    
    }    
};
search("Jones");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop in `search()` is looping too many times.

You had it right in `list()`, but in `search()`, you made a little error.

You have:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks so much, those are the errors that drive you crazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

// printPerson added here
var printPerson = function(person){

    console.log(contacts[0].firstName + " " + contacts[0].lastName);
    console.log(contacts[1].firstName + " " + contacts[1].lastName);
};

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Typically, a "code only" answer isn't particularly helpful. In this case, you might want to add information about what parts of the code you fixed, and why it was broken. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777 FREE",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888 FREE",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list() {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}

function search(lastName) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        if (lastName === contacts[i].lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        };
    };
};
search("Jones");

function add(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber){
    object = {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName, 
        email: email, 
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };
    contacts[contacts.length] = object;
};

add("firstName", "lastName", "name@example.com", "32874683275");
list();
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer